# How to get vscode to recognize included headers from external packages in a c++ bazel project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, bazel

I am working on a c++ project with bazel BUILD system in the vscode IDE environment. To illustrate, one could take one of the large open source projects such as tensorflow.

While the intellisense functionality works very well for source/header dependencies within the project folder itself, vscode seems unable to recognize headers included from third_party/external dependencies, such as protobuf headers in the tensorflow project (see below screenshot). So is there a way for vscode to recognize such headers, with the help of both c++/clang and bazel plugins?

[image]

To provide more details:

This protobuf header is included by the following BAZEL target in tensorflow/lite/toco/BUILD,

```
cc_library(
    name = "toco_port",
    srcs = [
        "toco_port.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "format_port.h",
        "toco_port.h",
        "toco_types.h",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:framework_lite",
        "//tensorflow/core:lib",
        "//tensorflow/core:lib_internal",
        "@com_google_absl//absl/status",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_headers",
    ],
)
```

which in turn is defined by the following workspace rule in tensorflow/workspace2.bzl

```
tf_http_archive(
    name = "com_google_protobuf",
    patch_file = ["//third_party/protobuf:protobuf.patch"],
    sha256 = "cfcba2df10feec52a84208693937c17a4b5df7775e1635c1e3baffc487b24c9b",
    strip_prefix = "protobuf-3.9.2",
    system_build_file = "//third_party/systemlibs:protobuf.BUILD",
    system_link_files = {
        "//third_party/systemlibs:protobuf.bzl": "protobuf.bzl",
        "//third_party/systemlibs:protobuf_deps.bzl": "protobuf_deps.bzl",
    },
    urls = tf_mirror_urls("https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v3.9.2.zip"),
)
```

The downloaded external repository is usually stored in a local directory ~/.cache/_bazel, specified by the --output_user_root flag in bazel.

Comment: You mentioned clang, so you're not using the stock C++ autocompletion, but rather something clang-based? For clangd, you generate `compile_commands.json`, and it finds every dependency based on that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use the default c/c++ plugin provided by microsoft, as well as "C/C++ Extension Pack", and "Better C++ Syntax". Another one I have installed is "C/C++ Clang Command Adapter".  Do you believe compile_commands.json can solve this issue? I can try it if you do.

Comment: My favorite setup is uninstalling Microsoft's C++ extension (the default one), installing the clangd extension, then telling your build system to generate `compile_commands.json` (not sure how to do it with bazel, but there has to be a way), then all dependencies are detected automatically. For the stock C++ extension do detect them, I believe you need to manually set the include paths somewhere.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat looks like there is a long process https://gist.github.com/bsilver8192/0115ee5d040bb601e3b7.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on that gist, I (the author of it) now recommend https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-compilation-database instead.

Comment: If you a working with Linux consider to use CLion - it has a great working Bazel Plugin